# require_once Inside require_once Creates Path Issue

Tags: php

I have this condition :

- a file : `/public_html/folderX/test.php` has a line : `require_once '../functions/sendemail.php'`
- on the other hand, `/public_html/functions/sendemail.php` has a line : `require_once '../config.php'`

`config.php` loads perfectly in this situation.

the problem occurs when I try to add that `functions/sendemail.php` on file(s) which not in the folderX, for example :

when I tried to add `require_once 'functions/sendemail.php'` on `public_html/test.php` I got this error message :

> Warning: require_once(../config-min.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in public_html/test.php

how to make `require_once '../config.php'` inside functions/sendemail.php works 'independently' so wherever it's included on any files this 'require_once' problem won't occur anymore.

I tried to change into 'include_once' but still doesn't work.

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try  something like

```
require_once( dirname(__FILE__).'/../config.php')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `__DIR__` to attain the current path of the script.

```
require_once(__DIR__.'../config.php');
```

`__DIR__` only works on php 5.3

```
 __DIR__ 

The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of 
the included file is returned. This is equivalent to dirname(__FILE__). 
This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory. 
(Added in PHP 5.3.0.)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the relative path names are biting you here. Relative paths are (to my knowledge) based on the directory of the currently active script. PHP doesn't `chdir` into a folder when `including` or `requiring` files. The best recommendation (in my limited experience) for this kind of thing is to use absolute paths where possible. So something like:

```
require_once('../config.php');
```

would become:

```
require_once('/home/myuser/config.php'); // Or wherever the file really is
```

The [dirname](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) function can help in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You must understand that PHP changes directory to that of the *outermost* script. When you use relative paths (e.g. those that begin with `./`, `../`, or those that do not begin with `/`), PHP will use the current directory to resolve the relative paths. This causes problem when you copy-paste the include lines in your code. Consider this directory structure:

```
/index.php
/admin/index.php
/lib/include.php
```

Assume the two index files contain these lines:

```
include_once("lib/include.php");
```

The above line will work when `/index.php` is called but not when `/admin/index.php` is called.

The solution is to not copy-paste code, use correct relative file paths in your include calls:

```
/index.php       -> include_once("lib/include.php");
/admin/index.php -> include_once("../lib/include.php");
```